# Как из коллекции получить данные не переводя его в массив. Отношения многие ко многим. Eloquent

Tags: laravel, коллекции, eloquent

```
    $categories = Category::find(1);
    $array = $categories->contents->toArray();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    echo $array[0]['pivot']['category_id'];
    die;
```

Как из коллекций $categories получить contents, без массива?

Модель category.php

```
    public function contents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Content');
}
```

Comment: а именно нужен pivot->content_id

Comment: А зачем ? у тебя же есть массив контентов теперь `contents` ну и возьми там id, так как ты написал можно получить доступ к "экстра полям", например если бы у тебя там был active в таблице

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#available-methods